# Unable to open Compass after OS X El Capitan (10.11) update

Tags: ruby, macos, compass-sass, compass

I updated to OS X El Capitan (10.11) and now my grunt script is not working.

When I run compass like:

```
compass version
```

I get:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:wnmu thegreyspot$ compass version
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.1.0.alpha.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried to run `sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin` and `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass` to no success.

I have updated XCode in the app store. So I am at 7.0.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix the permissions with

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /Library/Ruby
```