# Compass not working after el capitan install

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, compass-sass, compass

When i use compass watch it doesn't see any changes on el capitan.
On mavericks it works and detects everything.

Does someone know what is a fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972968/cant-install-gems-on-macos-x-el-capitan?s=1|3.9883 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021069/unable-to-open-compass-after-os-x-el-capitan-10-11-update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. It is due to Apple implementing System Integrity Protection (SIP). You have to first disable that...

**Reboot in recovery mode:**

Reboot and hold **Command + R** until you see the apple logo.

Once booted select **Utilities > Terminal** from top bar.

type: `csrutil disable`

then type: `reboot`

**Once rebooted**

Open terminal back up and enter the commands:

`sudo gem uninstall bundler`

`sudo gem install bundler`

`sudo gem install compass`

`sudo gem install sass`

`sudo gem update --system`

The the individual gems that failed need to be fixed, so for each do the following:

*On my machine this was the first dependency not working so I listed it*:

`sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.3`

Proceed through the list of gems that need to be repaired. In all you are looking at about 10 minutes to fix it, but you will have terminal commands for compass working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwDc4.jpg)

Comment: This answer worked for me, upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan. If some of the "pristine fixes" are failing, make sure xcode cli tools is installed.

Answer (score 7):

I'm no expert on Mac OS, but it looks like the OS wants us to install to `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/user/bin` from now on. So I installed compass using:

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass`

Comment: If you believe this question is a duplicate of another question (hint: check the comments), you should vote to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Tried @jbalesteri answer but doesn't work for me. I updated ruby to version 2.2.3 and now work fine. Below are all the commands I used to update if someone need it as reference.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
brew update
rvm install ruby-2.2.3
rvm use ruby-2.2.3
gem update --system
gem install compass
```